# Neo4j: Mismatch between in-browser query and C# Driver.V1 request results

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a relationship between two created nodes using C# application with `Neo4j.Driver.V1` from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4j.Driver). But the query returns unexpected empty result in case when I'm waiting a single line.
So how the request looks in code:

[image: Request]

I take this info from `IStatementResult` object to see what the real request was proceed. And the parameters for this query are:

[image: Params]

This statemend returned me nothing. It can be okay if there are no suitable `:Album` or `:Account` entity. But simple request in browser shows me next result:

[image: Return result]

And the same request with `CREATE` statemend that I need:

[image: Create result]

As soon as there are no supported profilers or any technique that can show the real requests to the database how can I be sure what the statement server try to execute and why I see some unexpected results?

Comment: In your code, in the match for both _src and _trg Ids, you have quotes around your ids: `"{sourceId}"` and `"{targetId}"`. Your parameters seem to include the quotes already, when you inspected them. What happens if you lose the quotes here?

Comment: @InverseFalcon: these fields in parameters object have string type, that's why VS shows quotes in inspector. If I'll remove them from query without modifying parameters, an exception will be thrown by query builder with `unexpected '-' symbol after supposed Id value`. I have another `CREATE` query that use the same parameters technique (but itonly creates a single node) and the same `RETURN` works well. Maybe this is an idea to take out quotes from query expression but this is odd as for me. But I will have to try if there will be no obvious ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As **@InverseFalcon** wrote, there was a mismatch in queries: some of them was created as formatted string, some of them used text with templates and properties object. So, it was complex mistake with quotes and expression create way.